# Overclocking Raspberry Pi after the device has booted

Tags: pi-3, raspi-config, performance, overclocking

I using a Raspberry-Pi 3B+ device and I am trying to change the maximum frequency after the device has booted. From my understanding, this can be done by editing the files under

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/
```

But the problem is I cannot increase the scaling_max_frequency from the value it already shows. Example:

```
$sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
600000

$sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
600000

$cpupower frequency-set -f 800MHz

$sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
600000

$sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
600000
```

I have already switched the Power governor to userspace. I am also aware that the kernel sets this value during the boot process but is it possible anyway to change the max frequency after the device has booted?

Thank you for any help I can get on this issue.

Comment: `editing the files under` - they are not regular files, so, no, you misunderstand - you do not set cpu speed by editing those files

Comment: You actually do. The files in /sys directly control the kernel's turbo mode, which is what changes the CPU clock frequency in response to processing demands. By "editing" I meant changing the values in the files (in the mentioned location), which is pretty intuitive.

Comment: editing, to me, suggests using something like vi/vim/nano :p